# How to create every possible pairs of sets?

Tags: python, set, combinations, permutation

I have two lists of n elements each with no common elements between the two sets:

```
SetA= [a1, a2 ... an]

SetB= [b1, b2 ... bn]
```

I would like to generate every possible pair of lists `SetX` and `SetY` such that `SetX` has half the elements from `SetA` and half the elements from `SetB`, and `SetY` has the remaining elements from `SetA` and `SetB`.

Is there a way to do this in `Python`?

Comment: You should be able to do this with `itertools`.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this, but please add more details, input, expected output. What have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked @Barmar's comment and came up with this solution:

```
import itertools

s1= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
s2= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
u= s1 + s2
n= len(s1)

total= 0
for subs1 in itertools.combinations(s1, int(n/2)):
    for subs2 in itertools.combinations(s2, int(n/2)):
        total= total + 1
        x= list(subs1)
        x.extend(list(subs2))
        y= list(set(u) - set(x))
        print(x)
        print(y)
        print('--------')
print(total)
```